# Website URL not being attached to Tweet message when Tweeting from fancybox image popup

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

I've set up a Fancybox image gallery on my [website](http://www.teganwhitesel.com/#painting), and integrated social sharing on each image popup box. The problem I'm having is that when someone goes to Tweet the website's URL is not being attached to the pre-populated Twitter message.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong because I followed this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G5TC3/) tutorial on how to integrate social button with Fancybox and the code seems almost identical to mine...

Here is my JS for the social buttons:

```
$('.fancybox-buttons')
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',

        prevEffect : 'none',
        nextEffect : 'none',


    beforeShow: function () {
        if (this.title) {
            // New line
            this.title += '<br />';

            // Add tweet button
            this.title += '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="Amazing work by artist Tegan Whitesel!" data-count="none" data-url="' + this.href + '">Tweet</a>';

            // Add FaceBook like button
            this.title += '<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=' + this.href + '&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=500&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=23" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:110px; height:23px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';

            // Add Pinterest "Pin It" button
            this.title += '<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://www.teganwhitesel.com/#painting&media=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.teganwhitesel.com%2Fpainting%2Fbeginnings-3_b.jpg&description=Tegan%20Whitesel%20-%20Beginnings%20III" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="none"><img border="0" src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" /></a>';


        }
    },
    afterShow: function () {
        // Render tweet button
        twttr.widgets.load();
    },
    helpers: {
        title: {
            type: 'inside'
        }, //<-- add a comma to separate the following option
        buttons: {} //<-- add this for buttons
    },
    closeBtn: true, // you will use the buttons now
    arrows: true
});
```

and here is the additional script tag in my `index.html` `<header>` section of my site:

```
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```